# API response in JS format

Tags: javascript

I'm using openai API to get the filtered response in JS format, how can I add the response retrieved from API to the script tag in my HTML?

I'm logging the response and pasting it manually works.

I'm completely noob. Sorry for bad explanation.

Comment: The same way you add anything else to your HTML in JS. Assign to the `.innerText` of an element.

Comment: the response is JS and I want to add to the script tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const url = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js'
// download data
fetch(url).then(r => r.text()).then(data => {
  // create a script
  const script = document.createElement('script')
  // add code to the script
  script.textContent = data
  // insert script to the html
  document.body.appendChild(script)
})
```